# Move two reference lines in JFreechart

Tags: graph, line, jfreechart, interactive

I am using JFreechart - createLineChart and plotting some data. I want to set two thresholds; one upper and another lower. To represent the same I want to draw reference lines. User must be able to drag these lines to adjust the values for upper and lower thresholds. Is it possible to implement? Till now I could only draw the graph with dataset.I could even get the mouse click(x,y) coordinates in pixel. I have no clue how to add new lines to the graph and make them drag. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Along with CrosshairOverlay, I used multiple annotations. Following link helped me a lot! Thanks.
[JFreeChart: Dynamic point selection in ChartPanel using ChartMouseListener and mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188142/jfreechart-dynamic-point-selection-in-chartpanel-using-chartmouselistener-and-m)